# How to program this puzzle recursively?

Tags: python, logic, puzzle

So I solved a brainteaser in my head, but i'm having a difficult time translating it to a recursive definition. The brainteaser is the broken weight problem (https://mathlesstraveled.com/2010/05/01/the-broken-weight-problem/):

*A merchant had a forty pound measuring weight that broke into four pieces as the result of a fall. When the pieces were subsequently weighed, it was found that the weight of each piece was a whole number of pounds and that the four pieces could be used to weigh every integral weight between 1 and 40 pounds. What were the weights of the pieces?*

So, the answer is  (1,3,9,27) which can be generalized as twice the sum of previous terms + 1.

I'm trying to write a python function to recursively return the nth term of the sequence and im having a difficult time of it because i'm not that good at recursion yet. I kind of figured out that I have to return the running sum as well....

This is incomplete code of my thought process so far:

```
def x(n):
  if n == 1:
    sum = term = 1 
      return (sum, term)
  else:
    term = (sum*2)+1
    sum = sum+term
    return (sum,term)
```

This code is broken and will raise a "local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment" error. How can I best think about this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the code you are looking for:

```
def _x(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return (1,1)
    else:
        oldsum, oldterm = _x(n-1)
        newterm = 2*oldsum + 1
        newsum = oldsum+newterm
        return (newsum, newterm)

def x(n):
    return _x(n)[1]
```

Example:

```
>>> x(1)
(1, 1)
>>> x(2)
(4, 3)
>>> x(3)
(13, 9)
>>> x(4)
(40, 27)
>>> x(5)
(121, 81)
```

The confusion may have been old vs new sums/terms.

Comment: is it possible to have it return only one value? the nth term? x(4) = 27

Comment: @foursuits I added a wrapper function that could be used to only get the term. Unfortunately, the sum needs to be returned from the recursive function since it is needed in the other iterations.